# Can anyone explain on when to use vielleicht and wahrscheinlich?

Tags: standard-german

I often hear people saying this word *wahrscheinlich*.

I generally use *vielleicht*. Is it correct?

Could anyone explain some examples if there is any difference between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would argue that "wahrscheinlich" (possibly, likely) is generally a bit more probable than "vielleicht" (maybe).

"Vielleicht" leans more to the side of the subject being vague or even unlikely. It can also be used to make a polite excuse for not showing up to some event ("Vielleicht komme ich vorbei.").

"Wahrscheinlich" leans more on the probability for the subject to happen. While it still leaves room for the subject not happening, it is an indication of confidence nonetheless.

Examples:

> Vielleicht gewinne ich morgen im Lotto

It is unlikely that i will actually win the lottery, but there is a chance for it.

> Wahrscheinlich kaufe ich mir trotzdem morgen wieder einen Lotto-Schein.

Even though there is a possibility that i will not buy a lottery ticket tomorrow, my habit is that i buy one every day, so it is very likely that i will buy one again.

Comment: Every day? Every week?